# Como gerar links para paginação com limites?

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma paginação cujo os resultados geram grande quantidade de links-números.

Cenário:

- tenho `10.000` (dez mil) registros sendo paginados.
- A paginação deverá ser de `30` em `30`;
- Porém, os links não podem exibir `333` links, mas apenas `15`. E esses links, vão dinamicamente sendo exibidos de acordo com a página atual.

Exemplo:

```
1 .. 15

16 .. 30

30 .. 40

317 ... 333
```

Porém desejo fazer isso, deixando a página atual "no meio" desses links.

Exemplo:

```
 Página 35 exibe de 28 à 43
```

Se eu clicar em 320.

```
317 ... 333
```

Como poderia fazer isso em PHP?

**Observação**: Já consegui fazer isso no Laravel 4, mas acho que a pergunta vai ajudar algumas pessoas que têm essa dificuldade (e que não usam um framework).

**Exemplo de paginação com pontos nos links no Laravel 4**:

```
@for ($i = $initial = max(1, $paginator->getCurrentPage() - 15), $l = min($initial + 20, $paginator->getLastPage()); $i <= $l; $i++)

    @if($paginator->getCurrentPage() == $i)
        <a class="item active">{{ $i }}</a>
    @else
        <a href="{{ $paginator->getUrl($i) }}">{{ $i }}</a>
    @endif

@endfor
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272108/logic-behind-pagination-like-google

Comment: Recompenso ou não recompenso? Eis a questão!

Comment: Não precisa... eu apenas informei um link de uma resposta ja dada aqui mmesmo

Comment: @JeffersonSilva aqui mesmo? stack overflow != stack overflow em portugues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acabei decidindo publicar minha própria resposta.

Eu criei uma função para poder gerar um range de números de acordo com o limite passado.

A lógica é a seguinte: Se tenho `55` paginas e quero limitar a `10`. Será exibido `5` itens antes e `5` depois da página atual. Caso a página atual seja o valor inicial que é `1`, os `5` que deveriam ser exibidos antes de `1` são acrescentados ao final. Se o valor limite for `55`, então exibimos `10` antes de `55` (ou seja `45`).

A ideia é que os resultados fiquei assim:

```
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 [2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 [3] 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 [4] 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 [5] 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 [6] 7 8 9 10
2 3 4 5 6 [7] 8 9 10 11
3 4 5 6 7 [8] 9 10 11 12

44 45 46 47 48 [49] 50 51 52 53 54
45 46 47 48 49 [50] 51 52 53 54 55 
45 46 47 48 49 50 [51] 52 53 54 55  
45 46 47 48 49 50 51 [52] 53 54 55

45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 [55]
```

Para isso criei a seguinte função:

```
/**
 * @param int $current Página atual
 * @param int $total Total da Paginação
 * @param int $limit Limite de links exibidos
 * @param int $start_at Valor inicial. Geralmente o Padrão é 1
 * @return \Generator
 */
function range_limit($current, $total, $limit = 10, $start_at = 1)
{
    $middle = ceil($limit / 2);

    $current = max($start_at, min($total, $current));

    $start = $current - $middle;

    $end = $middle + $current;

    if ($start <= $start_at) {
        $start = $start_at;
        $end = $limit;

    } elseif ($end >= $total) {
        $end = $total;
        $start = $total - $limit;
    }

    for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) yield $i;
}
```

Para usar, basta fazer assim:

```
  range_limit($pagina_atual, $ultima_pagina, $limite_de_links);
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/6oH0Ca).

Em um caso mais próximo do real, poderia ficar assim:

```
 $pagina_atual = $_GET['pagina'] ?? 1;

 $limite_da_paginacao = 15;

 // Se for 1, é 0
 // Se for 2, é 15
 // Se for 3, é 30
 // Se for 4, é 45
 $offset = ($pagina_atual * $limite_da_paginacao) - $limite_da_paginacao;

 $resultado = query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM usuarios")->primeiro();

 $ultima_pagina = ceil($resultado->total / $limite_da_paginacao);

 $limite_de_links = 10;

 $dados = query("SELECT * FROM usuarios LIMIT ? OFFSET ?", $limite, $offset)->todos();
```

Para gerar os links, bastaria fazer:

```
  <?php foreach(range_limit($pagina_atual, $ultima_pagina, $limite_de_links) as $pagina): ?>
      <a href="index.php?pagina=<?=$pagina?>"><?= $pagina ?></a>
  <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Como na pergunta está citado que a resposta deve prover uma solução para usuários iniciantes, então tentei fazer o exemplo mais simples possível, com o cálculo mais simples que consegui pensar.

**Passo a passo**

A paginação é o processo de separar muitos resultados de alguma busca, logo é obrigatório termos um objeto para ser manipulado nessa paginação. No exemplo esse objeto é um `array` simples de `string` onde cada `string` representa uma página (seja ela um artigo, ou lista de produtos, etc).

Outra coisa que devemos levar em consideração é em resguardar a página atual em que o usuário está, a demonstração usa o `GET` do `PHP` para armazenar e informar o valor da página atual para o usuário.

A última coisa é pensar no objetivo, que é além de exibir o conteúdo da página selecionada, mostra o link para `X` páginas anteriores e `X` páginas posteriores da página atual. Logo definimos algumas variáveis, como:

- `display` - que armazena o valor definido como quantidade máxima de
  links de páginas.
- `middle` - que é apenas a variável anterior    dividida por 2 para
  informar quantas páginas antes e depois da página    atual iremos
  buscar.

Após tomar conhecimento dos requisitos para fazer tal paginação, partimos para o código:

**pager.php**:

```
<?php
// array que simula o objeto a ser paginado, que normalmente é resultado de uma busca na persistência
$pages = array
(
    'page01', 'page02', 'page03', 'page04', 'page05',
    'page06', 'page07', 'page08', 'page09', 'page10',
    'page11', 'page12', 'page13', 'page14', 'page15',
    'page16', 'page17', 'page18', 'page19', 'page20',
    'page21', 'page22', 'page23', 'page24', 'page25',
    'page26', 'page27', 'page28', 'page29', 'page30',
);

// Resgata número página atual da URL, o padrão é 1
$current = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

// Informa número de links para navegação de páginas a ser mostrado
// de preferência ser ímpar, para que possa haver um meio exato para página atual
$display = 7;

// se a página existir
if(array_key_exists($current - 1, $pages)):
    // exibe conteúdo da mesma
    echo "<h1>Current page: {$pages[$current - 1]}</h1>";

    // define o meio dos links, defino um contador com o mesmo valor
    // ele auxiliara na hora de mandar x links para direito e x para esquerda
    $middle = $cont = (int)($display/2);

    // Percorre de 0 até o limite de links
    for($pg = 0; $pg < $display; $pg ++):
        // Se não é o meio da quantidade de links
        if($pg != $middle)
        {
            // Se for uma página anterior
            if($pg < $middle)
            {
                // Página será igual a atual menos o contador
                $page = $current - $cont;
                // Decrementa contador, para que a proxima pagina seja +1
                $cont --;
            }
            // Se for uma página posterior
            else if($pg > $middle)
            {
                // Define numero da página, como atual + contador + 1 (que indica que já passou a página atual também)
                $page = $current + $cont + 1;
                // Incrementa contador, para que a proxima pagina seja +1
                $cont ++;
            }
            // Exibe o link apenas se a página tiver no intervalo de resultados
            if($page > 0 and $page <= count($pages))
                echo "<a href='pager.php?page={$page}'>{$page}</a> | ";
        }
        // Se for a página atual (estará no meio)
        else
        {
            // Exibe o link em negrito
            echo "<strong><a href='pager.php?page={$current}'>{$current}</a></strong> | ";
        }
    endfor;
// Se a página não existir
else:
    echo "<h1>Page not exists!</h1>";
endif;

?>
```

Comment: Cara sou iniciante em php, eu não entendi a parte do GET['page'], inicial, onde diz que o padrão é 1, mas a nomeação dos valores do array está como "01"... Pode me dar uma breve esclarecida ?

Comment: @MagicHat Na linha eu olho, se existe parâmetro get, se sim eu armazeno o valor do get em current, se nao eu armazeno o numero um, supondo que a primeira página é a 1. No array são apenas exemplos de conteúdo, voce pode edita-lo normalmente, o que importa no caso é a chave do array que no caso vai de 0 até 29, onde zero humanizando, significa a página 1, e assim por diante até a página 30. O conteúdo do elemento do array seria o texto da página, nada mais. Espero ter esclarecido nesse texto breve.